# I can't get a java application to work on lubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, java

I want to play FTB unleashed and I can not get it to work. I have looked around and couldn't find any good help.

Comment: You should provide us with more info in order for us to be able to solve your problem. Did you get any error messages? What happened when you tried to open the .jar file?

Comment: when i open the .jar file it just brings me into the archiver wich is of no help to me to try to run it

Answer (score 0):

Using the commands in the terminal:

```
chmod +x [filename].jar
java -jar ./[filename].jar
```

Comment: there is no open with just open and also i installed the ubuntu restricted access package wich includes open jdk7

Comment: i get this errorThe program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless

Comment: then install it: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre`

Comment: thank you i beleive it is now working i appreciate the patients

Comment: the patients also appreciate you

Comment: i only have one more question it is complaining about it not being an exacuteable how do i make it one edit fixed it in properties

Comment: @Twitch_Blade `chmod +x [filename].jar`. But better look for it around.